# Flutter adding support drag from Right to Left to sample code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

In the code provided here in its entirety, `drag-and-drop` from `left to right` works perfectly, allowing me to display the underlying widget. Now, the change I want to introduce is how I can also add `drag-and-drop` from `right to left` to it, so that I can move the top widget to the left side.

What I mean is, how can I add the reverse drag-and-drop operation from left to right to it?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyHome();
}

class _MyHome extends State<MyHome>  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  final double maxSlide = 225.0;
  final double minDragStartEdge = 150.0;
  final double maxDragStartEdge = 250.0;
  bool _canBeDragged = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragStart: _onDragStart,
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
        onHorizontalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
            final slide = maxSlide * _animationController.value;
            final scale = 1 - (_animationController.value / 0.20);
            return Stack(
              children: [
                const Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'TEST',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 32.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..translate(slide)
                    ..scale(scale),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: Container(
                      color:Colors.white,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu)),
                              const Text('Appbar'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'TEXT',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 32.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    final isDragOpenFromLeft = _animationController.isDismissed &&
        details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge;
    final isDragCloseFromRight = _animationController.isCompleted &&
        details.globalPosition.dx > maxDragStartEdge;
    _canBeDragged = isDragOpenFromLeft || isDragCloseFromRight;
  }

  void _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (_canBeDragged) {
      final delta = details.primaryDelta! / maxSlide;
      _animationController.value += delta;
    }
  }

  void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_animationController.isDismissed || _animationController.isCompleted) {
      return;
    }
    if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx.abs() >= 165.0) {
      final visualVelocity = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx /
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      _animationController.fling(velocity: visualVelocity);
    } else if (_animationController.value < 0.5) {
      closeDrawer();
    } else {
      openDrawer();
    }
  }

  void openDrawer() {
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  void closeDrawer() {
    _animationController.reverse();
  }
}
```

i think editing this part of code is enough.

```dart
  void _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    final isDragOpenFromLeft = _animationController.isDismissed &&
        details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge;
    final isDragCloseFromRight = _animationController.isCompleted &&
        details.globalPosition.dx > maxDragStartEdge;
    _canBeDragged = isDragOpenFromLeft || isDragCloseFromRight;
  }
```

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77285489/timeline) probably attracted at least one [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1):

That would take care of the transition from right to left. _canBeDragged name a little bit confusing here, but anyway:

```
void _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final delta = details.primaryDelta! / maxSlide;

    if (_canBeDragged) {
      _animationController.value += delta;
    } else {
      _animationController.value -= delta;
    }
  }
```

Other changes that makes sense at the animation:

```
  void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_animationController.isDismissed || _animationController.isCompleted) {
      return;
    }

    if (_animationController.value < 0.3) {
      closeDrawer();
    } else {
      openDrawer();
    }
  }
```

Also I would swap `Scaffold` with `GestureDetector` so that when the drawer is opened the whole screen listens for drag.

Answer (score 0):

To allow drag-and-drop from right to left, you need to modify the `_onDragStart` method to consider both directions. Here's the updated code for the `_onDragStart` method that allows reverse drag-and-drop:

```
void _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
  final isDragOpenFromLeft = _animationController.isDismissed &&
      details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge;
  final isDragCloseFromRight = _animationController.isCompleted &&
      details.globalPosition.dx > maxDragStartEdge;
  _canBeDragged = isDragOpenFromLeft || isDragCloseFromRight;
  if (_animationController.isCompleted && details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge) {
    _canBeDragged = true;
    _animationController.reverse();
  }
}
```

In this updated `_onDragStart` method, we first check if the user starts a drag from the left side, and if so, `_canBeDragged` is set to `true`. Additionally, we check if the user starts a drag from the right side while the drawer is open (i.e., `_animationController.isCompleted`), and if so, we set `_canBeDragged` to `true` and reverse the animation to close the drawer. This will allow you to drag the widget from right to left to close the drawer.

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided allows for a left-to-right drag to reveal the underlying widget. To also enable a right-to-left drag to move the top widget to the left side, you'll need to make some adjustments.

Here's the modified code:

```
void _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    final isDragOpenFromLeft = _animationController.isDismissed &&
        details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge;
    final isDragCloseFromRight = _animationController.isCompleted &&
        details.globalPosition.dx > maxDragStartEdge;
    final isDragOpenFromRight = _animationController.isDismissed &&
        details.globalPosition.dx > maxDragStartEdge;
    final isDragCloseFromLeft = _animationController.isCompleted &&
        details.globalPosition.dx < minDragStartEdge;
    _canBeDragged = isDragOpenFromLeft || isDragCloseFromRight || isDragOpenFromRight || isDragCloseFromLeft;
  }

  void _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  if (_canBeDragged) {
    final delta = details.primaryDelta! / maxSlide;
    _animationController.value += delta;
  }
}

void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
  if (_animationController.isDismissed || _animationController.isCompleted) {
    return;
  }
  final moveRight = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0;
  if (moveRight) {
    if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx.abs() >= 165.0) {
      final visualVelocity = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx /
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      _animationController.fling(velocity: visualVelocity);
    } else if (_animationController.value < 0.5) {
      closeDrawer();
    } else {
      openDrawer();
    }
  } else {
    if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx.abs() >= 165.0) {
      final visualVelocity = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx /
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      _animationController.fling(velocity: visualVelocity);
    } else if (_animationController.value > 0.5) {
      openDrawer();
    } else {
      closeDrawer();
    }
  }
}
```